# Creating a toggled, appearing, sliding div with HTML and CSS (and maybe jquery?)

Tags: jquery, css, html, sliding

Hey so I'm trying to create a webpage where I can click a button and a section will slide out from underneath a title, revealing content. As it slides out all elements underneath it should also slide down.

I've kind of got this working with just HTML and CSS... My method is where you click on the  which is to slide out itself, and as you click and hold it will slide down. Once you release the click the div slides back up.

This is done via this CSS placed on the slide-out div:

```
#slide-out {
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in;
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 73px;
  margin-top: -98px;
  position: relative ;
}

#slide-out:active {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

And here is the HTML to accompany that:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="section-title">Project</div>    

    <div id="slide-out">
    Test
    </div> <!-- of slide out -->

    <div class="section-title">The Team</div>

</div>
```

However I would like it so that:

- the height can be much larger without any following elements being affected
- i don't need to hold down the button for it to slide out (more of a toggle mechanism)
- i can click on a button which is not the div slide-out or anything contained in the div slide-out

Thanks a lot!

what i used to do my code so far: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/slide-out-panel-css3/

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

You'll probably have to resort to JS to get the child elements to slide out after the first element has finished its run.

Answer (score 0):

Why limit yourself to webkit?   Jquery slideDown() can do what you need be offer more cross-browser compatibility: 
http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/